# Is there a way to get the argument of argparse in the order in which they were defined?

Tags: python, argparse

I'd like to print all options of the program and they are grouped for readability. However when accessing the arguments via `vars(args)`, the order is random.

Comment: I really doubt it considering argparse and other things like it are designed to conform to the POSIX standard where the order they are specified is not supposed to matter. You could probably do it using `sys.argv` but then they are not parsed.

Comment: Are you interested in the order in which arguments appear the commandline, or the order in which they are created with `add_argument`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`argparse` parses the list of arguments in `sys.argv[1:]` (`sys.argv[0]` is used as the `prog` value in `usage`).

`args=parser.parse_args()` returns a `argparse.Namespace` object.  `vars(args)` returns a dictionary based on this object (`args.__dict__`).  Keys of a dictionary are unordered.  `print(args)` also uses this dictionary order.

The parser keeps a record of seen-actions for its own bookkeeping purposes.  But it is not exposed to the user, and is an unordered `set`.  I can imagine defining an custom `Action` subclass that recorded the order in which its instances were used.

---

It is possible to retrieve arguments in the order in which they were defined when creating the parser.  That's because the `parser` has a `_actions` list of all the `Actions`.  It's not part of the public API, but a basic attribute and unlikely to every disappear.

To illustrate:

```
In [622]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [623]: parser.add_argument('foo')
In [624]: parser.add_argument('--bar')
In [625]: parser.add_argument('--baz')

In [626]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--bar BAR] [--baz BAZ] foo

positional arguments:
  foo

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --bar BAR
  --baz BAZ
```

The usage and help listings show the arguments in the order that they are defined, except that `positionals` and `optionals` are separated.

```
In [627]: args=parser.parse_args(['--bar','one','foobar'])
In [628]: args
Out[628]: Namespace(bar='one', baz=None, foo='foobar')
In [629]: vars(args)
Out[629]: {'bar': 'one', 'baz': None, 'foo': 'foobar'}

In [631]: [(action.dest, getattr(args,action.dest, '***')) for action in parser._actions]
Out[631]: [('help', '***'), ('foo', 'foobar'), ('bar', 'one'), ('baz', None)]
```

Here I iterate on the `_actions` list, get the `dest` for each `Action`, and fetch that value from the `args` namespace.  I could have fetched it from the `vars(args)` dictionary just as well.

I had to give `getattr` a default `***`, because the `help` action does not appear in the namespace.  I could have filtered that sort of action out of the display.