# Python: Typehints for argparse.Namespace objects

Tags: python, pycharm, argparse, type-hinting, python-typing

Is there a way to have Python static analyzers (e.g. in PyCharm, other IDEs) pick up on Typehints on `argparse.Namespace` objects?  Example:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--somearg')
parsed = parser.parse_args(['--somearg','someval'])  # type: argparse.Namespace
the_arg = parsed.somearg  # <- Pycharm complains that parsed object has no attribute 'somearg'
```

If I remove the type declaration in the inline comment, PyCharm doesn't complain, but it also doesn't pick up on invalid attributes.  For example:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--somearg')
parsed = parser.parse_args(['--somearg','someval'])  # no typehint
the_arg = parsed.somaerg   # <- typo in attribute, but no complaint in PyCharm.  Raises AttributeError when executed.
```

Any ideas?

---

#### Update

Inspired by [Austin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42279784/7007605) below, the simplest solution I could find is one using `namedtuples`:

```
from collections import namedtuple
ArgNamespace = namedtuple('ArgNamespace', ['some_arg', 'another_arg'])

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--some-arg')
parser.add_argument('--another-arg')
parsed = parser.parse_args(['--some-arg', 'val1', '--another-arg', 'val2'])  # type: ArgNamespace

x = parsed.some_arg  # good...
y = parsed.another_arg  # still good...
z = parsed.aint_no_arg  # Flagged by PyCharm!
```

While this is satisfactory, I still don't like having to repeat the argument names.  If the argument list grows considerably, it will be tedious updating both locations.  What would be ideal is somehow extracting the arguments from the `parser` object like the following:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--some-arg')
parser.add_argument('--another-arg')
MagicNamespace = parser.magically_extract_namespace()
parsed = parser.parse_args(['--some-arg', 'val1', '--another-arg', 'val2'])  # type: MagicNamespace
```

I haven't been able to find anything in the `argparse` module that could make this possible, and I'm still unsure if *any* static analysis tool could be clever enough to get those values and not bring the IDE to a grinding halt.

Still searching...

---

#### Update 2

Per hpaulj's comment, the closest thing I could find to the method described above that would "magically" extract the attributes of the parsed object is something that would extract the `dest` attribute from each of the parser's `_action`s.:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--some-arg')
parser.add_argument('--another-arg')
MagicNamespace = namedtuple('MagicNamespace', [act.dest for act in parser._actions])
parsed = parser.parse_args(['--some-arg', 'val1', '--another-arg', 'val2'])  # type: MagicNamespace
```

But this still does not cause attribute errors to get flagged in static analysis.  This is true also true if I pass `namespace=MagicNamespace` in the `parser.parse_args` call.

Comment: A quick google says that you can use type hints on the first use of local variables. Try it on `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() # type: argparse.Namespace` and see if it works.

Comment: @Austin:  `parser` in this case is an `argparse.ArgumentParser` object, not an `argparse.Namespace` object.  I want the `parsed` object to be populated with the args as attributes.

Comment: You're right. I missed `parsed` vs. `parser.` What you really want seems to be that PyCharm parses the method arguments when building your ArgumentParser. I doubt that works well.

Comment: `add_argument` returns the `Action` object it just created.  Look at its attributes.  `parser._actions` is a list of all these actions, which the parser uses during parsing.  I've mentioned them in previous SO answers.

Comment: In your new edits, are you passing the new namespace to the `parse_args`?

Comment: More on `parser._actions`, http://stackoverflow.com/a/40007285 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/39282787

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[Typed argument parser](https://github.com/swansonk14/typed-argument-parser) was made for exactly this purpose. It wraps `argparse`. Your example is implemented as:

```py
from tap import Tap


class ArgumentParser(Tap):
    somearg: str


parsed = ArgumentParser().parse_args(['--somearg', 'someval'])
the_arg = parsed.somearg
```

Here's a picture of it in action.
[image]

It's on PyPI and can be installed with: `pip install typed-argument-parser`

Full disclosure: I'm one of the creators of this library.

Comment: This is a solid library, but very basic. It lacks things like callbacks and doesn't support typed subparsers well, which are problems I found after spending an hour on it. While it seems like an exciting project (and they seem to have plans to resolve these issues), as of April 2022, imo it isn't a usable replacement for a moderately complex use of argparse.

Comment: I would really recommend using the `namespace` argument to `parse_args` as mentioned by @aghast in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42279784/15429). With Python 3.6 and up you can define your own `Namespace` class with arguments that only has type hints.

Answer (score 32):

Consider defining an extension class to `argparse.Namespace` that provides the type hints you want:

```
class MyProgramArgs(argparse.Namespace):
    def __init__():
        self.somearg = 'defaultval' # type: str
```

Then use `namespace=` to pass that to `parse_args`:

```
def process_argv():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--somearg')
    nsp = MyProgramArgs()
    parsed = parser.parse_args(['--somearg','someval'], namespace=nsp)  # type: MyProgramArgs
    the_arg = parsed.somearg  # <- Pycharm should not complain
```

Comment: The `defaultval` defined in this class over rides any default parameters defined in the parser methods.  That's probably is desirable.  But it's a detail to watch out for when using custom namespaces.

Comment: The `__init__` is not needed for Python 3.6 and up, instead add the attributes with a type hint (no value). ```somearg: str```

Comment: Using the namespace isn't necessary here as it's designed to be used to assign attributes to an existing object, `nsp` in this case, but you're accessing the parsed args from `parsed` instead of `nsp`. Your last two lines should be changed to either, 1, exclude using namespace and use class for type annotation `parsed: MyProgramArgs = parser.parse_args(...)`, or 2, keep `namespace=nsp`, don't assign to `parsed`, and access/assign via `the_arg = nsp.somearg`. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77063478/6811686) for more details.

Answer (score 20):

Most of these answers involve using another package to handle the typing. This would be a good idea only if there wasn't such a simple solution as the one I am about to propose.

#### Step 1. Type Declarations

First, define the types of each argument in a dataclass like so:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyProgramArgs:
    first_var: str
    second_var: int
```

#### Step 2. Argument Declarations

Then you can set up your parser however you like with matching arguments. For example:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("This CLI program uses type hints!")
parser.add_argument("-a", "--first-var")
parser.add_argument("-b", "--another-var", type=int, dest="second_var")
```

#### Step 3. Parsing the Arguments

And finally, we parse the arguments in a way that the static type checker will know about the type of each argument:

```py
my_args = MyProgramArgs(**vars(parser.parse_args())
```

Now the type checker knows that `my_args` is of type `MyProgramArgs` so it knows exactly which fields are available and what their type is.

Comment: Very good solution. Would be more involved if you had multiple subparsers I guess. I think you'd need different data classes with different attributes then. And each of these would have to share a parent class.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat for multiple subparsers I suppose you could have a different class for each subparser, then based on the first arg you can choose which class to instanciate

Comment: I still like this approach, but mypy cannot validate the types. If first_var is not a string, mypy will not complain.

Comment: Remark: This solution is working but exactly what OP doesn't like: "I still don't like having to repeat the argument names"

Answer (score 6):

I don't know anything about how PyCharm handles these typehints, but understand the `Namespace` code.

`argparse.Namespace` is a simple class; essentially an object with a few methods that make it easier to view the attributes. And for ease of unittesting it has a `__eq__` method.  You can read the definition in the `argparse.py` file.

The `parser` interacts with the namespace in the most general way possible - with `getattr`, `setattr`, `hasattr`.  So you can use almost any `dest` string, even ones you can't access with the `.dest` syntax.

Make sure you don't confuse the `add_argument` `type=` parameter; that's a function.

Using your own `namespace` class (from scratch or subclassed) as suggested in the other answer may be the best option.  This is described briefly in the documentation.  [Namespace Object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-namespace-object).  I haven't seen this done much, though I've suggested it a few times to handle special storage needs.  So you'll have to experiment.

If using subparsers, using a custom Namespace class may break, http://bugs.python.org/issue27859

Pay attention to handling of defaults.  The default default for most `argparse` actions is `None`.  It is handy to use this after parsing to do something special if the user did not provide this option.

```
 if args.foo is None:
     # user did not use this optional
     args.foo = 'some post parsing default'
 else:
     # user provided value
     pass
```

That could get in the way type hints.  Whatever solution you try, pay attention to the defaults.

---

A `namedtuple` won't work as a `Namespace`.

First, the proper use of a custom Namespace class is:

```
nm = MyClass(<default values>)
args = parser.parse_args(namespace=nm)
```

That is, you initial an instance of that class, and pass it as the parameter.  The returned `args` will be the same instance, with new attributes set by parsing.

Second, a namedtuple can only created, it can't be changed.

```
In [72]: MagicSpace=namedtuple('MagicSpace',['foo','bar'])
In [73]: nm = MagicSpace(1,2)
In [74]: nm
Out[74]: MagicSpace(foo=1, bar=2)
In [75]: nm.foo='one'
...
AttributeError: can't set attribute
In [76]: getattr(nm, 'foo')
Out[76]: 1
In [77]: setattr(nm, 'foo', 'one')    # not even with setattr
...
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

A namespace has to work with `getattr` and `setattr`.

Another problem with `namedtuple` is that it doesn't set any kind of `type` information.  It just defines field/attribute names.  So there's nothing for the static typing to check.

While it is easy to get expected attribute names from the `parser`, you can't get any expected types.

For a simple parser:

```
In [82]: parser.print_usage()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-foo FOO] bar
In [83]: [a.dest for a in parser._actions[1:]]
Out[83]: ['foo', 'bar']
In [84]: [a.type for a in parser._actions[1:]]
Out[84]: [None, None]
```

The Actions `dest` is the normal attribute name.  But `type` is not the expected static type of that attribute.  It is a function that may or may not convert the input string.  Here `None` means the input string is saved as is.

Because static typing and `argparse` require different information, there isn't an easy way to generate one from the other.

I think the best you can do is create your own database of parameters, probably in a dictionary, and create both the Namespace class and the parsesr from that, with your own utility function(s).

Let's say `dd` is dictionary with the necessary keys.  Then we can create an argument with:

```
parser.add_argument(dd['short'],dd['long'], dest=dd['dest'], type=dd['typefun'], default=dd['default'], help=dd['help'])
```

You or someone else will have to come up with a Namespace class definition that sets the `default` (easy), and static type (hard?) from such a dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

If you are in a situation where you can start from scratch there are interesting solutions like

- the already mentioned [typed argument parser (TAP)](https://github.com/swansonk14/typed-argument-parser)
- [typer](https://github.com/tiangolo/typer)
- [typed-args](https://github.com/SunDoge/typed-args)

However, in my case they weren't an ideal solution because:

1. I have many existing CLIs based on `argparse`, and I cannot afford to re-write them all using such args-inferred-from-types approaches.
2. When inferring args from types it can be tricky to support all advanced CLI features that plain `argparse` supports.
3. Re-using common arg definitions in multiple CLIs is often easier in plain imperative argparse compared to alternatives.

Therefore I worked on a tiny library [typed_argparse](https://github.com/bluenote10/typed_argparse) that allows to introduce typed args without much refactoring. The idea is to add a type derived from a special `TypedArg` class, which then simply wraps the plain `argparse.Namespace` object:

```py
# Step 1: Add an argument type.
class MyArgs(TypedArgs):
    foo: str
    num: Optional[int]
    files: List[str]


def parse_args(args: List[str] = sys.argv[1:]) -> MyArgs:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--foo", type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--num", type=int)
    parser.add_argument("--files", type=str, nargs="*")
    # Step 2: Wrap the plain argparser result with your type.
    return MyArgs(parser.parse_args(args))


def main() -> None:
    args = parse_args(["--foo", "foo", "--num", "42", "--files", "a", "b", "c"])
    # Step 3: Done, enjoy IDE auto-completion and strong type safety
    assert args.foo == "foo"
    assert args.num == 42
    assert args.files == ["a", "b", "c"]
```

This approach slightly violates the single-source-of-truth principle, but the library performs a full runtime validation to ensure that the type annotations match the argparse types, and it is just a very simple option to migrate towards typed CLIs.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it which could be ideal if you have few arguments is as follows.

First make a function that sets up the parser and returns the namespace. For example:

```py
def parse_args() -> argparse.Namespace:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-a")
    parser.add_argument("-b", type=int)
    return parser.parse_args()
```

Then you define a main function which takes the args you declared above individually; like so.

```py
def main(a: str, b: int):
    print("hello world", a, b)
```

And when you call your main, you do it like this:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(**vars(parse_args())
```

From your main onwards, you'll have your variables `a` and `b` properly recognised by your static type checker, although you won't have an object any more containing all your arguments, which may be a good or bad thing depending on your use case.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR: Namespace isn't necessary, use the class as a type annotation. Works with passing through functions/methods as well. Supported all the way down to python3.5**

```py
class MyProgramArgs(argparse.Namespace):
    my_arg1: str
    my_arg2: dict[str, str]

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--my_arg1')
    parser.add_argument('--my_arg2')

    parsed: MyProgramArgs = parser.parse_args()

    the_arg1: str = parsed.my_arg1             # <- Pycharm should not complain
    the_arg2: dict[str, str] = parsed.my_arg2  # <- Pycharm should not complain
    the_arg3: str = parsed.my_arg2             # <- Pycharm SHOULD complain
```

---

**Details:**
As I was unable to respond to @aghast's answer, I want to provide the simplest solution to this that I was able to arrive at after working through this for a couple weeks.

Using the namespace isn't necessary in his implementation (per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-namespace-object)) as it's designed to be used to assign attributes to an existing object, `nsp` in his case, which aghast didn't use in his solution, e.g.

```py
# bad, not using instantiated MyProgramArgs() object
nsp = MyProgramArgs()
parsed = parser.parse_args(['--somearg','someval'], namespace=nsp)
the_arg = parsed.somearg  # <- Pycharm should not complain

# using namespace properly
nsp = MyProgramArgs()
parser.parse_args(['--somearg','someval'], namespace=nsp)  # note no assignment
the_arg = nsp.somearg  # Properly accessing assigned attributes from provided namespace object
```

Either:

1. Don't instantiate `nsp` as it's unused, use the class as the type annotation for the variable(s), and skip namespace entirely, e.g. `parsed: MyProgramArgs = parser.parse_args()`.
2. Use namespace properly per the docs and my example above.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea because you're just lying to the type checker. Maybe your IDE won't care, but if you try to call isinstance on the object it won't agree with the static type which will probably confuse other people maintaining your code. It's no significant extra overhead or code bloat to just add the namespace=MyNamespace() argument.

Comment: Also it looks like at least with VS Code's type checker the return type can be inferred from the namespace argument so no redundant annotation is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

a `super` solution to just type hint the `NameSpace` return value of `parse_args` method.

```py
import argparse
from typing import Type


class NameSpace(argparse.Namespace, Type):
    name: str


class CustomParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def parse_args(self) -> NameSpace:
        return super().parse_args()


parser = CustomParser()

parser.add_argument("--name")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args.name)
```

[image: PARSED ARGS]

Comment: This can be shortened by passing ```namespace=NameSpace()``` to the `parse_args()` method. No need for the custom parser. Also the `NameSpace` class doesn't need to inherit `Type`, at least from Python 3.6 and up.

Comment: This does not pass mypy :/ "Invalid base class "Type"", "Signature of "parse_args" incompatible with supertype "ArgumentParser""

Answer (score 1):

Here's Jason Leaver's solution with amos's suggested improvement:

```py
import argparse

class Namespace(argparse.Namespace):
    name: str

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--name")

args = parser.parse_args(namespace=Namespace())
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to contribute here with a little more involving solution that focus on the OP's concerning:

> *While this is satisfactory, I still don't like having to repeat the argument names. If the argument list grows considerably, it will be tedious updating both locations. What would be ideal is somehow extracting the arguments from the parser object*

This solution doesn't use external packages. It uses `dataclasses` to define the arguments, just like [Abraham Murciano's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71035314/9761768) but the extraction of the arguments is made with the `fields` function. All the definition are made inside the `Args` dataclass.

I also added some typing tools to make the solution be complete type checked.

I'm using [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) inside VS Code, which makes use of [Pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright) type checker.

### 1. Some definitions

Function `make_arg` will be used to create "args fields" and `add_args` will add the arguments

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import argparse
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, fields
from typing import Sequence, Callable, Any

def make_arg(
    name: str | Sequence[str] | None = None,
    action: str = "store",
    nargs: int | str | None = None,
    const: Any = None,
    default: Any = None,
    type: Callable[[str], Any] = str,
    help: str = "",
    metavar: str | Sequence[str] | None = None,
):
    arg_dict = locals()
    if name is not None and not name[0].startswith("-"):
        raise ValueError("`name` should be passed only to flagged args")
    if isinstance(name, str):
        arg_dict["name"] = [name]
    if arg_dict["action"] in ["store_true", "store_const"]:
        arg_dict.pop("nargs")
        arg_dict.pop("const")
        arg_dict.pop("type")
        arg_dict.pop("metavar")
    arg_dict.pop("default")
    return field(default=default, metadata=arg_dict)

def add_args(args_cls: type[Args], parser: argparse.ArgumentParser):
    for arg in fields(args_cls):
        arg_dict = dict(arg.metadata)
        if arg_dict["name"] is None:  # no flagged arg
            arg_dict["name"] = [arg.name]
        else:  # flagged arg
            arg_dict["dest"] = arg.name
        arg_name = arg_dict.pop("name")
        parser.add_argument(*arg_name, **arg_dict)
```

### 2. Usage

All the args definition are made inside the `Args` dataclass with the function `marke_arg`, just once.

```py
@dataclass
class Args:
    some_arg: str = make_arg()
    flagged_arg: str = make_arg(name="--another-arg")

# Create the parser object
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

# Add the args using the dataclass and the parser
add_args(Args, parser)

parsed = parser.parse_args(
    ["val1", "--another-arg", "val2"],
    namespace=Args(),
)

x = parsed.some_arg  # good...
y = parsed.flagged_arg  # still good...
z = parsed.aint_no_arg  # Flagged by PyLance!
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution if you don't need your parsed args class to inherit from Namespace:

```
@dataclass
class MyTypedArgs:
    input_path: str
    output_path: str
    verbose: bool

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Does stuff, very useful")
    
    # ... add some args

    args = parser.parse_args()
    return cast(MyTypedArgs, args)
```

You can get fancier than this by implementing some of the Namespace class by hand if you end up needing to (or cast back to Namespace).