# What is the Python equivalent to the C++ namespace?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In C++ I would write:

```
namespace LowerLevel{
int DoStuff() {}; //
}
```

And access it via:

```
LowerLevel::DoStuff()
```

How do I do both in Python?

Comment: You have several options: a module, a class, a dictionary etc

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga don't forget packages

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The closest in spirit would be to use a module.

In a file `lower_level.py` you'd have

```
def do_stuff():
  pass
```

and then elsewhere you'd do:

```
import lower_level
lower_level.do_stuff()
```

---

EDIT / addendums: That's the simple way. There's things like packages, where you'd have a folder `lower_level`, and inside that folder is an `__init__.py` identifying `lower_level` as a package. Inside that package you'd have `.py` files that'd be modules, or you put certain imports and declarations into the `__init__.py`. But it can also just remain empty. I guess packages would amount to nested namespaces.

```
- prog.py
\MyNameSpaceA
    - __init__.py # just an empty file
    - ObjA.py # A python Module
    \SubPackageB
       - __init__.py
       - ObjB.py # another python module
```

Comment: And of course there's a bunch of variations on that theme, for example `from lower_level import do_stuff` and that puts `do_stuff` into the namespace of the importing module. Or you do the EVIL and NOT RECOMMENDED `from lower_level import *` and then everything from `lower_level` is in the importing namespace...

Comment: Or a package (don't forget `__init__.py`!), which is really just a folder with modules in it.

Comment: How would I do nested namespaces? SpaceA::SpaceB::DoStuff()?

Comment: See my addendum. Packages, implemented as nested folders

Comment: @Dan In newer versions of Python, `__init__.py` is no longer required.

Answer (score 2):

One more option is to define everything in a function and return the locals. The advantage is that all definitions are in the same scope, so they can reference each other without any prefixes. Also you can have many of these in the same file.

```py
import argparse

def InitLowerLevel():
    def DoStuff():
        return 1
    def DoOtherStuff():
        return DoStuff()
    kFoo = 0
    return argparse.Namespace(**locals())

lower_level = InitLowerLevel()

lower_level.DoStuff()
```

Comment: `argparse` is used for taking command line arguments into the program. I don't see any reason to use it for anything else...

Comment: @Tomerikoo `argparse.Namespace` is convenient for this case, and `argparse` is a standard module,
so why not use it.
any alternative?

Comment: yeah well I guess you're right, I mean it's convenient to  use the `**kwargs` option in the constructor. It's just that a `Namespace` object is very basic and you could do that with any other object, even a function.

Answer (score 0):

The `argparse` module may also be an option to consider, depending on your use case. The original answer is what I would say the better Software Development best practice, but this module provides the functionality you originally asked for.

It allows the dot notation to set and get variables. But complains less than dicts for when you are trying to add new variables/functions.

**Python 3**

```py
>>> import argparse
>>> def my_test_function(): return
>>> ...
>>> args = argparse.Namespace()
Namespace()
>>> args.minutes  = 5
>>> args.test = my_test_function
>>> args
Namespace(minutes=5, test=<function times_close_enough at 0x000001D2BEEAA550>)
```

Although the proper way to use `argparse` can be found at its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) 
, some further examples can be found on this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42279063/python-typehints-for-argparse-namespace-objects) (helps if you understand better by example!)

Comment: I think the "Namespace" is for "object will be built up from attributes parsed out of the command line" (ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#parsing-arguments). Isn't different from "namespace" in C++ that provided a method for preventing name conflicts in large projects (ref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace)?

Comment: The original intention of Namespace is as you say, as referenced at the bottom of my answer. But let us consider *how* the C++ "namespace" is used: it is an opt-in way of including variables/functions/etc. The original answer of using the Python "module" approach, automatically makes the "namespace" name based on the filename, but does not allow controlling (ie. opt-in) without definition of the `__all__` special variable. In all cases the Python approach is not a direct parallel as there is no true equivalent, just an application of its features that suits the OPs use case.