# Better option to provide type hints for argparse arguments than a custom namespace

Tags: python, argparse, type-hinting, mypy

I am trying to use mypy to type check my program. The program uses argparse to parse command line arguments. I want to add type hints for the command line arguments.

```py
import argparse
import typing


# define example types and a function that uses them
Seconds = typing.NewType("Seconds", float)
Minutes = typing.NewType("Minutes", float)

def sec_to_min(s: Seconds) -> Minutes:
    return Minutes(s / 60)

# specify arguments and parse them
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-t", "--time", default=1., type=float,
                    help="time in seconds")
args = parser.parse_args()

try:
    # mypy reveals type Any
    reveal_type(args.time)
except NameError:
    pass


# (1) passes type check
seconds: Seconds = args.time
# (2) passes type check
sec_to_min(args.time)
```

I would like mypy to recognize `args.time` as `Seconds`. The current code should recognize `args.time` as float and complain since passing a float to `sec_to_min` complains as well.

I tried changing the `type` argument of `add_argument` to `type=lambda x: Seconds(float(x))`. This had no effect, mypy still identified `args.time` as `any`.
As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42279063/python-typehints-for-argparse-namespace-objects), I have also tried to provide a custom NameSpace. This changed the revealed type of `args.time` to `Seconds`. I would like to avoid this, since I would have to duplicate the name for every argument and the default value from `add_argument` is overridden by the custom namespace.

```py
class TypedNameSpace(argparse.Namespace):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.time: Seconds = Seconds(0.)
        super(TypedNameSpace, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: The argparse `type` parameter is a function that converts a string to something, and raises an error if it can't.  It does not add typehints information.  Values are placed in the namespace with general purpose `setattr`. I doubt if mypy can trace this action through argparse code.

Comment: @hpaulj I know, I was just hoping there is something I missed in my search. Seems like the only way to add type hints is to duplicate the parameters.

Comment: Oops, I should have checked your link; I gave a much longer answer, but same basic  idea, two years ago.

Comment: I tend to avoid tools like argparse and instead do manual command line argument parsing.  It's much easier for something like mypy or pylint to scrutinize.  I be happy to switch to argparse once it becomes less risky though.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a custom namespace is the way to go. You don't have to assign a default value to the names. Just type hinting each name at the class level would be enough for mypy to recognize the type of the attribute at the instance level:

```
class TimeNamespace(argparse.Namespace):
    time: Seconds

...

args = parser.parse_args(namespace=TimeNamespace())

# mypy reveals type "__main__.Seconds"
reveal_type(args.time)
```

Demo of the code passing mypy: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=4028679c0e89a2c2f609aa2592486e0c

Demo of the code successfully using the default value of `1.` for `--time` and outputs `0.016666666666666666`: https://ideone.com/8KEGgb